# Is it possible to use a static member function as C callback by C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following function defined in a C library:

```
void f(void (*callback)(int)) { callback(0); }
```

which will be called from a C++11 program defining the callback() as below:

```
struct S {
    static void S::callback(int) noexcept {}
};

f(&S::callback);
```

Most compiler would probably compiler the above without any warnings, but, my question is, if strictly speaking, I must declare the callback as (a free) extern "C" function to be totally compliant with C++11 standard.

Comment: Pointers to static member functions can be used as C function pointers.

Comment: `extern "C"` is necessary because it makes the C++ linker look for the C-symbol of the function rather than the C++ name–mangled symbol of the function. Since here you don’t deal with the function name, but with the function actual address, there is no need for `extern "C"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifications as `extern "C"` are for control of the names of functions, variables etc. But in your case `S::callback` address is passed as the argument in runtime, so the name of the function is not relevant, and no specification is necessary.

Comment: This is not exactly true; there are some rare cases where `extern "C"` actually changes calling convention (I can't remember which specific environment that was, but I remember one such weird thing existing).